# css :focus-visible for custom control

Tags: html, css, onfocus

a `:focus-visible` is always shown for `input` & `textarea`, and always shown for `button` *only if* the focus switched using `tab` key.

The question is: how about a custom control made of `<div tabIndex="0">....</div>`.
Sometimes a complex custom control is easier made from `<div>` & `<span>` and styled like a native control.
How to make `button like <div>` working with `:focus-visible`?
How to make `textarea like <div>` working with `:focus-visible`?
How to tell to css that the specified `<div class="my-custom-ctrl">` is a button or text editor?

[See my sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/focus-visible-for-customcontrol-gk9nc)

Comment: Can you share some codes you tried so far?

Comment: i've updated the post, see my sandbox

Answer (score 2):

Use `tabindex` and it will work.

```css
.focusable:focus-visible {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div tabindex="0" class="focusable">
Can be focused
</div>

<div>
Can NOT be focused
</div>

<div tabindex="0" class="focusable">
  Can be focused
</div>

<div>
Can NOT be focused
</div>
<div tabindex="0" class="focusable">
Can be focused
</div>

<div>
Can NOT be focused
</div>

<div tabindex="0" class="focusable">
  Can be focused
</div>
```

Comment: i've updated the post, see my sandbox